# Android Studio - Gradle plugin missing from offline maven repository

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After downloading android studio 2.3, i keep getting this error in the event log,

```
      illegalStateException: Gradle plugin missing from offline maven repository
```

Anyone knows how this can be fixed?

I have Gradle version 3.3, also im not sure if this is relatable to the error above but everytime i click create new project nothing at all happens, but when i click create new module and choose phone module I'am able to go through choosing name of activity but then it doesn't get created!

Comment: Seems you are in offline mode or cannot connect to download the Gradle plugin

Comment: i had offline work for global gradle setting enabled but even after i disabled it , i still get this error

Comment: You need to re-sync or try buliding the project after disabling. Otherwise, the needed plugins won't download

Comment: A simple reinstall solved this issue for me. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634855/unable-to-launch-new-android-studio-project

Comment: reinstall includes download all components again?

Comment: Once I encountered the same problem.I found it is lacks the directory "m2repository" in my install directory "\AndroidStudio\gradle".I just copy the directory from my colleague,and the problem be solved.

Comment: @cricket_007, Yes, I know I'm offline and I won't be able to go online. how to fix it manually? where do I put the files? how to instruct A-Studio to read the plugin from an specific folder?

Comment: @AaA you have to be online or point your Gradle file at a local mirror of Jcenter / Maven Central. That's the only way I know about. There's too many files needed to copy that there's no clear way to answer your question. If you do have anything else to ask, please create a new post for it, not ask in the comments

Comment: Honestly i just reinstalled it again to fix the issue, will try the options said in these posts if it ever happens again. Thank you!

Comment: @cricket_007, I won't go online and if someone try to go online in my network, he is fired, while half my company was crippled from latest ransomware, my department was the only one that wasn't affected. I didn't ask what files, I already know the files. I also have a Maven in my local network, I also know how to set gradle to read from that maven. my problem is A-Studio, refuses to read from there and gives me strange error messages that need a decoder to find what it means!

Comment: @cricket_007, There is no hijacking happened here. Even if I posed a new question it would be same and marked as duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have this file "m2repository" under the Gradle file [image].

Comment: Where is the gradle file? what do you mean by under the gradle file?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem after updating the studio plugin, unable to create a new project. I can only reinstall the solution, do not know where the problem.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221536

Answer (score 1):

*Although I'm professionally programming for past 27 years, I'm just starting to program with android as hobby in my spare time, so I don't have very clear knowledge of A-Studio or android yet. Also I'm not sure if I have to categorize this as bug or incorrect configuration of the project.It would be great if someone with greater knowledge in this matter verify it.*

I was getting this error for past few days while trying to build a simple project. The error message is not helping as it makes you feel something is wrong with your repository. To find out what is actually going o, I tried different scenarios. I don't have Internet connection in my test machine, so `Android Studio` won't be able to download or update anything (neither `Java` or `Gradle`).

**Here is the test:**

I have a very simple project that is configured to compile and build using  local gradle against a local Maven repository. Compiling from command line is successful.

[image: Gradle build commandline]

Next, I open the project in Android-Studio which is configured to use same gradle distribution. Please note that selecting `Use local gradle distribution` or `default` does not make any difference in outcome of this test. I'm using **`Android Studio version 2.3.3`**

[image: Gradle settings in Android-Studio]

Next, I build the project which compile, build and package successfully.

[image: Build with untouched A-Studio]

Next, I close A-Studio, clean project and rename the `\AndroidStudio\gradle` folder to `gradle1` which makes it unavailable to A-Studio.
I open A-Studio and open the project and soon I get error:

```
Gradle plugin missing from offline maven repository
```

To my surprise, project still compile, build and package correctly.

[image: Android studio without its gradle]

**Conclusion**

There is a version of gradle is bundled with Android studio which includes a local Maven repository with it. Even if your project does not use this bundled gradle, or the mentioned repository (`\AndroidStudio\gradle1\m2repository`), you still cannot delete or rename either one.

**How to fix it**

*If you are working online:*

Delete your `.gradle` folder which by default can be found at `$home` or `%username%`.
Re-install the Android Studio.

*If you are working offline (No Internet connection):*

If you can build your project without problem, just ignore the error message (or report bug to Google using `Help -> submit feedback` from `Android Studio`)

if your project doesn't build. you need to check your project settings and make sure you can compile it from command line using `gradlew` or `gradle` to make sure your project is configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For the record re-installing is not a solution.

this problem was mostly encountered by people who chose to install a gradle that did not come with android studio.

the solution is quite simple actually.

step1: locate your gradle where you installed it and move all the components to the file named gradle in android studio.

NB:if you dont have one(gradle file) then create one.

Step2: make sure all the files required are under that gradle file which include wrapper, daemon ,m2-repository ,(gradle 3.2/3.3 or both) it doesn't matter you can manually drag the individual files wherever you locate them and add them their.

most probably m2-repository is not their which is causing the problem

go to settings under gradle and change the path of gradle to your new gradle location.
after this restart gradle and your gradle should build successfully .

[image: first image]

[image: second picture]

[image: third picture]