# Unable to launch new android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio

When I click on the "new project" button in android studio 2.3 nothing happens and I get the following entry in the `idea.log`:

```
WARN - ctions.AndroidNewProjectAction - Unable to launch New Project Wizard 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Gradle plugin missing from the offline Maven repo
```

Offline work in gradle settings is disabled. Any other ideas?

Comment: Give it a try :- upgrade your gradle plugin version to 3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took my a few hours to solve this. A simple reinstall of android studio 2.3 (without a new download) made it work in the end.

Comment: I think you just needed to upgrade Android SDK Manager.

Comment: I just reinstalled the exact same android studio 2.3 without upgrading anything.

Comment: @AdrianKrebs does it include download all the component again, please give explained answer how you did