# Android Studio Gradle Project Failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I know this has been asked before, but w/e I try doesn't work. I tried both renaming and deleting my gradle folder. Then restart Android Studio. I tried downloading the latest gradle zip from http://services.gradle.org/distributions/ and put that folder in my android studio folder after delelting the other gradle folder. Is the most recent src.zip the one I should be getting or src.zip.sha or bin.zip? I tried invalidating caches and restarting as well. I tried downloading the NDE and restarting.

Anything else I can try? Why does this happen? Seems like it happens to enough people to get a little more support.

Edit: Adding IDE Fatal Error

> Gradle plugin missing from the offline Maven repo
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Gradle plugin missing from the
>   offline Maven repo    at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.plugin.AndroidPluginGeneration.getLatestKnownVersion(AndroidPluginGeneration.java:214)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.plugin.AndroidPluginGeneration$1.getLatestKnownVersion(AndroidPluginGeneration.java:69)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.post.PluginVersionUpgrade.log(PluginVersionUpgrade.java:70)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.post.PluginVersionUpgrade.checkAndPerformUpgrade(PluginVersionUpgrade.java:57)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.post.PostSyncProjectSetup.setUpProject(PostSyncProjectSetup.java:177)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.populate(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:166)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.access$000(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:51)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask$1.run(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:144)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: _"Android Studio Gradle Project Failed"_ with what error? Without looking into error log we can't help you. So, please [edit] the question and post error log.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42634855/1427849

Comment: edit your question and give it some time to format it correctly

Comment: Hey I'm not exactly sure if this is what you need, But I added a bug report. Right now, the gradle error is not showing because the build is now stuck waiting to finish. I see that it says gradle plugin missing, but I have tried replacing the original gradle file with gradle 4.4